# Printing Bidi text to an image

Tags: python, character-encoding, image-manipulation, multilingual, bidi

I have some code in Python using PIL, that will print UTF-8 characters to an image.

I've noticed that for joining Bidi scripts like Arabic, the same code fails to connect characters correctly (the initial forms are only chosen, medial and final forms aren't utilized)

Can anyone recommend a method or technique for solving this particular issue?

Comment: I've just had a quick look at their website, and my guess is that the library doesn't have the ability to properly handle BIDI. They certainly don't advertise it if they do.

Comment: Is [this](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-bidi/) of any help?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep using PIL, use [`pyarabicshaping`](https://github.com/behdad/pyarabicshaping) with [`pybidi`](https://code.google.com/p/pybidi/) or you might want to consider switching to [`pangocairo`](https://developer.gnome.org/pygtk/stable/class-pangocairocairocontext.html) which uses [`HarfBuzz`](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/HarfBuzz) for text shaping.

Answer (score 0):

What I did is the following: Python +**Wand**(Python Lib) +arabic_reshaper(Python Lib) +bidi.algorithme(Python Lib). The same applies to **PIL/Pillow**, you need to use the `arabic_reshaper` and `bidi.algorithm` and pass the generated text to `draw.text((10, 25), artext, font=font)`:

```
from wand.image import Image as wImage
from wand.display import display as wdiplay
from wand.drawing import Drawing
from wand.color import Color
import arabic_reshaper
from bidi.algorithm import get_display

reshaped_text = arabic_reshaper.reshape(u'لغةٌ عربيّة')
artext = get_display(reshaped_text)

fonts = ['C:\\Users\\PATH\\TO\\FONT\\Thabit-0.02\\DroidNaskh-Bold.ttf',
         'C:\\Users\\PATH\\TO\\FONT\\Thabit-0.02\\Thabit.ttf',
         'C:\\Users\\PATH\\TO\\FONT\\Thabit-0.02\\Thabit-Bold-Oblique.ttf',
         'C:\\Users\\PATH\\TO\\FONT\\Thabit-0.02\\Thabit-Bold.ttf',
         'C:\\Users\\PATH\\TO\\FONT\\Thabit-0.02\\Thabit-Oblique.ttf',
         'C:\\Users\\PATH\\TO\\FONT\\Thabit-0.02\\majalla.ttf',         
         'C:\\Users\\PATH\\TO\\FONT\\Thabit-0.02\\majallab.ttf',

         ]
draw = Drawing()
img =  wImage(width=1200,height=(len(fonts)+2)*60,background=Color('#ffffff')) 
#draw.fill_color(Color('#000000'))
draw.text_alignment = 'right';
draw.text_antialias = True
draw.text_encoding = 'utf-8'
#draw.text_interline_spacing = 1
#draw.text_interword_spacing = 15.0
draw.text_kerning = 0.0
for i in range(len(fonts)):
    font =  fonts[i]
    draw.font = font
    draw.font_size = 40
    draw.text(img.width / 2, 40+(i*60),artext)
    print draw.get_font_metrics(img,artext)
    draw(img)
draw.text(img.width / 2, 40+((i+1)*60),u'ناصر test')
draw(img)
img.save(filename='C:\\PATH\\OUTPUT\\arabictest.png'.format(r))
wdiplay(img)
```

[image: Arabic typography in images]