# Error ploting utf-8 labels

Tags: python-2.7, matplotlib, utf-8, arabic, axis-labels

I am trying to display plots but the labels are in `utf-8 Arabic`, `python2.7`.

```
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    labels = ['عشرة','عشرين','ثلاثين']
    #labels=['A','B','C']
    x = [10, 12,13]
    y = [10,20,30]
    plt.figure(figsize=(16, 16)) 
    for i in range(len(x)):
          plt.scatter(x[i],y[i])
          plt.annotate(labels[i],
                 xy=(x[i], y[i]),
                 xytext=(5, 2),
                 textcoords='offset points',
                 ha='right',
                 va='bottom')
    plt.show()
```

for the utf-8 (labels = ['عشرة','عشرين','ثلاثين']) I have error

> UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xd8 in position
>   0: ordinal not in range(128)

while it works fine when labels=['A','B','C'].

Comment: I have updated the matplotlib, by                                                      sudo pip install matplotlib --upgrade                                                The utf-8 Arabic words appeared, although they appeared with inverse ordering "let to right" . Now I need to solve the inner word to appear from right to left!

Answer (score 0):

I solved my Arabic font problem. I would like to share the solution in case any one needs it.

0- Be sure that your matplotlib is of the ver 2.2

to check

> import matplotlib
>
> matplotlib.**version**
>
> '0.98.0' % if this is the case, then you need to upgrade it

To upgrade

> sudo pip install matplotlib --upgrade

1- Install bidi

> sudo easy_install python-bidi

2- Install arabic_reshaper that will make the letters order from right to let

> sudo pip install arabic_reshaper

3-Change your code as following

```
    #!/usr/bin/python2.7
    # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
    from __future__ import unicode_literals
    import arabic_reshaper
    from bidi.algorithm import get_display
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    labels = ['عشرة','عشرين','ثلاثين']
    x = [10, 12,13]
    y = [10,20,30]
    plt.figure(figsize=(16, 16)) 
    for i in range(len(x)):
          a=arabic_reshaper.reshape(labels[i])
          aa = get_display(a)
          plt.scatter(x[i],y[i])
          plt.annotate(aa,
                  xy=(x[i], y[i]),
                  xytext=(5, 2),
                  textcoords='offset points',
                  ha='right',
                  va='bottom')
    plt.show()
```

For more information, 
https://matplotlib.org/faq/troubleshooting_faq.html

https://matplotlib.org/users/dflt_style_changes.html?highlight=changes%20default%20style

[Print Arabic words from Python to ESC/POS printer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38683686/print-arabic-words-from-python-to-esc-pos-printer)

http://mpcabd.xyz/python-arabic-text-reshaper/

Thanks